# SBT doesn't run correctly

Tags: scala, sbt

`SBT 1.0.3`, `java 8`, `windows 10 home`
When I type `sbt` in command line, I get

> Error: unable to access jarfile
>  Copying runtime jar.
>  Error:
>   unable to access jarfile
>   C:\Users\ #My user name here# \.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.3"\jars\sbt.jar

Then, looks like it runs, but doesn't resolve any dependencies.

**More info**:
There is no `preloaded` folder in my system.
Clean reinstall windows doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you decided to use sbt 1.0.3? try a bit older version http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html they seems to be more robust

Comment: sbt 1.0.3 works fine in another 3 computers. I want to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer, more of a comment**

Observed the same. On the beginning of this week sbt 1.0.3 worked all right, now I'm having this issue. Reinstalling sbt 0.13 does not help.

I'm afraid it is about some Windows updates.